# How can I assign a dynamic resource in the constructor when creating a frame in C# instead of XAML?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is the code that I currently have:

```
        var FR2 = new Frame()
        {
            Content = CE,
            CornerRadius = 5,
            HasShadow = false,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Padding = new Thickness(10, 0),
            Margin = new Thickness(0, 8),

        };
        FR2.SetDynamicResource(Frame.BackgroundColorProperty, "EntryBackgroundColor");
        FR2.SetDynamicResource(Frame.BackgroundColorProperty, "EntryBorderColor");
```

Is there a way I can set these dynamic resources

```
BackgroundColor
BorderColor
```

inside of the { } part of the constructor for FR2 instead of adding them after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. You cannot set the dynamic resources inside your initialiser. You have to set them afterwards with the `SetDynamicResource` method.

As you can see, [SetDynamicResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.element.setdynamicresource?view=xamarin-forms) expects to be used with `Element.SetDynamicResource()`. So, at least for now, this is not possible.

Taking into consideration that for the upcoming [MAUI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-multi-platform-app-ui/), the guys from Microsoft are spending more time into markup extensions for the code-behind, I won't be surprised if it comes in the near future.

Btw, you have a copy-paste mistake in the last row - you are binding the `EntryBorderColor` to the `BackgroundColorProperty` again.